# ADB: One system detects my device, the other one does not

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, device, adb

I have two systems, both are Windows 7 Ultimate x64. The Android device I am trying to connect is a Packard Bell Liberty Tab G100. My device is rooted, using stock ROM, application debugging is enabled.

First system detects my device perfectly, windows, adb and Eclipse:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
37c620043a0d557 device
```

The second one does not.

I have three tried three sets of drivers.

```
-Packard Bell Liberty Tab G100 Drivers
-Acer Iconia Tab Universal Drivers  (Liberty Tab is of the Acer Iconia family)
-Google USB Drivers from android SDK
```

First set of drivers did not work for both systems.
My first system uses the Acer Iconia Tab Universal Drivers as far as I know.
Its listed under Devices as following:

```
Liberty Tab G100
Driver Provider:   Microsoft
Driver Date:       21-6-2006
Driver Version:    6.1.7600.16385
Digital Signer:    Microsoft Windows
Driver files:
system32\DRIVERS\UMDF\WpdMtpDr.dll
system32\DRIVERS\winusb.sys
system32\DRIVERS\WUDFRd.sys
system32\WpdMtp.dll
system32\WpdMtpUS.dll
```

On my second system, the only drivers which I could install successfully were the Google USB Drivers using this workaround http://www.davinciunltd.com/2011/10/hacking-the-adb-usb-driver-for-acer-a500/

edit: I have installed the Acer Iconia Tab Universal Drivers, but they did not make my device detectable, it was still an unknown device.

Currently my device is detected on my second system as an ADB Interface, Android ADB Interface, Windows Device Manager showing me it uses Google's drivers.
ADB and Eclipse do not detect this device.

How do I get my second systems ADB and Eclipse to see the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself. If you're having the same problem or similar, this is how I solved it:

Install Acer Iconia Tab Universal Drivers.
Now open the Device Manager and click Update Driver Software for your device.
Browse my computer for driver software.
Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.
Show all drivers (loading might take a moment).
Navigate to Acer, there will be a few Acer variants, like Acer, Inc, ACER INCORPERATED and ACER or more.

Mine turned out to be Acer, Inc --> ACER Composite ADB Interface.
This makes my device detectable by ADB and Eclipse.